# What's the benefit of destroying leutenant Hammerman headquarters?

Tags: boom-beach

Destroying some of them is necessary to obtain the 2 doctor terror event and the colonel thingy.

What's the point of destroying the rest? I like to keep my victory points low.

Comment: Resources + the achievement?

Answer (score 4):

There is no real benefit aside from a huge amount of power stones, some resources and the achievement-diamonds you get from destroying his bases.

I wouldn't refuse to attack him just because of the +5 VP of each base. I would rather place my HQ to the beach for 5 raids to bring the VPs back if that's so important to you. :)